Reversing local changes from git merge
I recently made some changes locally to a git repo. Now some changes were made at the remote branch which I pulled and then accidentally accepted their versions of the files, including the ones that I changed. Hence, everything was deleted that I changed which is understandably very bad.
Is there any way in getting these local changes back?
I already tried with git restore and git stash but that didnt help as the changes weren't in the stash.

No unfortunately not as I also already tried this. The files were on my laptop and not commited to the local branch. I really have no idea how to fix this

Why was this closed? Maybe this question is a dup of something, but it's certainly not a dup of that question. OP already responded to that close request explaining why it isn't. (A quick search and I couldn't find a question where OP did not commit, did not stash, and maybe did not stage either, but I'd lean toward their being a question like this already somewhere...)

UPDATE: I didnt stage or stash it either but CLion has an integrated History log that shows the code that I edited, so thankfully I could revert the changes through this functionality.


I recently made some changes locally to a git repo.

If you did not commit, stash, or at least stage those changes, then unfortunately what you actually did was:

I recently made some changes locally.

If you never even told Git about those changes, and then you deleted those changes, unfortunately you won't be able to use Git to recover them. If some other tool on your system performs backups, perhaps you can use that instead.
If by chance you did stage the changes, you may be able to recover them.
